# Etiquette question: how to acknowledge Bugs Bunny?

Tags: soft-question, journals

Suppose that a mathematician such as Bugs Bunny answers one of my math questions here on MathOverflow, and then I use the idea in a research paper.  How should I acknowledge such a distinguished mathematician in my paper, submitted to a reputable journal and all that?

Comment: This should maybe be asked on meta. 

Comment: I would love to see a paper by tweetie-bird in a reputable journal.

Comment: @Benjamin: sorry, I wasn't sure where to ask this.  @KConrad: tweetie-bird isn't actually my name.

Comment: What? I'm shocked! So maybe the MO users Isomorphism, Turtle, and Physics Monkey aren't using their real names either? 

Comment: I think this is a question for meta. Here's a discussion (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4259/do-i-cite-mathstackexchange-in-my-paper#comment16303_4259) on meta MSE with a link to meta MO that asks this question as well.

Comment: The topic of pseudonyms has been discussed on http://tea.mathoverflow.net multiple times. If you don't find the answers you need in these discussions, start another thread there.

Comment: Several fundamental statistical tools are named after "Student," the name signed on the papers that introduced them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Sealy_Gosset

Comment: I know a practicing big-city hospital phlebotomist who officially changed his name to Bugs Bunny.

Comment: @KConrad I am not quite sure about your point. Do you mean that tweetie-bird would never be able to produce a paper in a reputable journal in their entire life?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Look right underneath where your question is posted.  Click on the "cite" link.  It will pop up a text box, from which you can copy citation data for this post in either bibtex or amsrefs format.  So you can directly cite the MO thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends how important is the help you have received. If it is a crucial step in your work and without it you were not able to complete the paper, you may want to suggest the helper to be your co-author. But if it is not that important you can send him/her an email and thank him/her and let him/her know that you will acknowledge his/her help at the end of the paper.

Comment: I believe the point is that the helper is not using his or her real name; for instance, the user Bugs Bunny: http://mathoverflow.net/users/5301/bugs-bunny .

Comment: That's right.  I wondered if this meant that all these people aren't interested in acknowledgment.  I hadn't known about meta and still don't know how to use it, but can see I probably should have asked this there.  Anyway, thanks. 